# check if timestamp is in certain range using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

Say I have a bunch of time stamps

As I iterate over these timestamps,

```
01:23:00
12:34:14
17:09:12
...
```

I want to include only timestamps  between 08:00:00 and 17:00:00

please suggest

Comment: @Andrei - presume those are hours:minutes:seconds - is that time window fixed, e.g. might you ever need a time window that crosses midnight?

Comment: possible duplicate of [compare time using date command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899110/compare-time-using-date-command)

Comment: The only difference between this and your previous question is that now you say you're looping over some input. If you need help looping, ask about that. If you need more help with date/time comparison, edit or comment on your previous question.

Comment: yes, it is not  duplicate as I am not using the current timestamp

Comment: @Andrei: I added that answer to the other question. It's a trivial extension of what was already there.

Answer (score 8):

You can do a simple string comparison:

```
if [[ "$timestamp" > "08:00:00" && "$timestamp" < "17:00:00" ]]
```

If you want to include the ends of your range, you'll have to test for that separately since Bash doesn't have a `>=` or `<=` operators for strings:

```
start="08:00:00"
end="17:00:00"
if [[ "$timestamp" == "$start" ||
      "$timestamp" >  "$start" && "$timestamp" <  "$end" ||
                                  "$timestamp" == "$end" ]]
```

Comment: I didn't know we could compare timestamps like this ... +1 Any possible pitfalls you see with this?

Comment: @JS웃: The example I show uses lexical comparisons and the OP's examples are all lexically sortable, so no I don't see any pitfalls under these conditions. You can even do it with full [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (or similar) dates. If you're using Unix epoch timestamps, just use a numeric comparison `if ((epoch_1 >= epoch_2))`